# Azure Active Directory - Scopes - Localisation

Tags: azure-active-directory

When you're defining a new scope (under "Expose an api") in an app registration, then you can fill out the scope's title and description.

[image]

Is there any way to localise / translate this? So that end-users can see the consent request in their own language?

I can't seem to find anything on the subject in the microsoft docs.

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the docs for permissionScope (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/permissionscope?view=graph-rest-beta) it doesn't seem that there is any localization support :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding localized names and descriptions is not currently possible. It's something that's planned, but no timeline to share at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philippe. Is there somewhere I can follow up on this in the future?

Comment: Adding support for this will result in an addition to Microsoft Graph, so the [Microsoft Graph changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/changelog) is probably your best bet.